# separate filename after underlining _ os.path

Tags: python, os.path

In my path `/volume1/xx/` are several files with this character `A_test1.pdf`, `B_test2.pdf`, ...I want to seperate the `test1` part without path and `.pdf`.

Im newbie so I tried first with full name
but I got only the "*.pdf" as a text. 
What is wrong with the path oder placeholder * ?

```
splitname = os.path.basename('/volume1/xx/*.pdf')
```

### Edit

I got 2019-01-18_RG-Telekom[] from orign ReT_march - I want 2019-01-18_RG-Telekom_march (text after underlining)   xx is a folder 
here is the whole code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import datetime
import glob
import os
import os.path

SOURCE_PATH = '/volume1/xx'
TARGET_PATH = os.path.join(SOURCE_PATH, 'DMS')

def main():

    today = datetime.date.today()

    splitnames = [os.path.basename(fpath) for fpath in glob.glob("./xx/*.pdf")]

    for prefix, name_part in [
        ('ReA', 'RG-Amazon'),
        ('GsA', 'GS-Amazon'),
        ('ReT', 'RG-Telekom'),
        ('NoE', 'Notiz-EDV'),
    ]:
        filenames = glob.iglob(os.path.join(SOURCE_PATH, prefix + '*.pdf'))
        for old_filename in filenames:
            new_filename = os.path.join(TARGET_PATH, '{}_{}_{}.pdf'.format(today, name_part, splitnames))
            os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What should be your expected output?

Comment: Input: ist ReA_Instar Kamera 9008.pdf Output should be: 2019-01-18_RG-Amazon_Instar Kamera 9008.pdf / 2019-01-18_RG-Amazon.pdf run, but the text after the underlining is my problem

Comment: Tony any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html), `os.path` don't know how to process masks, but `glob.glob` works:

```
splitnames = [os.path.basename(fpath) for fpath in glob.glob("./**/*.txt")]
splitnames 
Out:
['A_test1.pdf', 'B_test2.pdf']
```

Output of the glob:

```
glob.glob("./**/*.txt")
Out:
['./some_folder/A_test1.pdf', './another_folder/B_test2.pdf']
```

Apply `os.path.basename` to this list and extract basenames, as it shown above.

**Edit**
If `xx` in the path `volume1/xx/` is just a folder name, not a mask, you should use following expression:

```
splitnames = [os.path.basename(fpath) for fpath in glob.glob("./xx/*.txt")]
```

because `./**/` is expression which masks a folder name and it's unnecessary that case.

Comment: I got just a empty output []

Comment: You should edit your question instead of post an additional information as an answer. I can edit your question, but not now, because another edit is awaiting for approval. But it looks like `SOURCE_PATH = '/volume1/xx'` is absolute path (`/` is first symbol), but is should be relative. If you use linux, output of `tree` utility from a target folder will help, too. Post it, if tree is installed.